# Recycle View Adapter get data from retrofit sometimes NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, retrofit

I use `Retrofit` to get data from my local server and put there data on `recycle view`. But sometimes my android app exit because `recycleview`'s adapter cannot get data from `ArrayList` from `Retrofit` and sometimes it can work. And it can certainly get data when I debug it. Please help me, thanks. [this is my retrofit code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2n5Ys.png)        [this is a example error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N20Il.png)

Comment: put that lines into the try-catch block. because some of your data is coming null. you can check that data in logcat also try to add code here not images.

Comment: some time your image list getting null add check for you images

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the data is null before setting it to the adapter.

```
if(response.body().getData() != null) {
    postList = response.body().getData();
    adapter.setData(postList);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still exit sometimes. Response is certainly have data, but adapter cannot get data sometimes.

Comment: Maybe something went wrong during the deserialization. Did you check the raw response from the network? also, check the HTTP Response code.
Check raw response using `response.body().toString()`
and HTTP Response code using `response.code()`

Comment: Thanks, I think it's because of the version of Android system, this problem rarely occurs on the Android 8 virtual machine, but this problem occurs frequently on my Android 11 phone.